# How do you abstract without messing up your code?

Tags: c++, sfml, abstraction

I have a `render` function where I need to pass the window being rendered,and what components i want to draw.All components are derived from a class `sf::Drawable`.For example I can have an `sf::Text` saying hello or whatever,and an `sf::Rectangle` I want to draw.`sf::Drawable` is abstract so I cant create a data structure of `sf::Drawable` and then print each member of the structure.

Other alternatives I thought was to call `render` individually for each component but that is just messy code.I can overload render so it will take an `std::vector<sf::Text>` and another taking `std::vector<sf::Rectangle>` but that will create 7+ render functions,and I will need 7+ data structures holding these sf objects

How would I go about doing this the correct OOP way?

A little code for you to visualize:

```
    State s("123456780", texture); //State is derived from drawable
    std::vector<sf::Drawable> components;
    sf::Text str("You won!!!", font, 30);

    while (running) {
        sf::Event evant;
        onEvent(window, evant,s);
        if (s.equals(goal))
        {
            components.push_back(str);
        }else
            components.push_back(s);

        render(window, components);
    }
```

Compile error : `Error  C2259   'sf::Drawable': cannot instantiate abstract class   sfm`

Comment: You say, "`sf::Drawable` is abstract so I cant create a data structure of `sf::Drawable` and then print each member of the structure." Why not? That sounds like a textbook use case for polymorphism. Show us a little code to demonstrate where the conundrum lies.

Comment: I know right?But in c++ when say `std::vector<sf::Drawable> something` I get a compile error saying `You cant instantiate sf::Drawable because its abstract`.

Comment: @YosokuDenkai _"I know right?But in c++ when say `std::vector<sf::Drawable> something`"_ The compiler is right, you can't instantiate _abstract classes_ but `std::vector` requires that feature, you rather shoulfd use something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>> something`

Comment: @YosokuDenkai When you use a `sf::Drawable` object by value (through neither reference nor pointer), then that object is _always_ just an `sf::Drawable`. For polymorphism, you need a level of indirection. You should probably store a `vector<unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>>`.

Comment: @alter Hi Igel, nice to meet you again ;)

Comment: I edited a little code.Do i need to use smart ptrs?I am not familiar with them yet

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and alterigel are right -- you need to use (preferably smart) pointers, not values in your vector to do traditional compile-time polymorphism. (There are some relatively obscure alternatives, e.g., run-time polymorphism. See [Sean Parent's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg) or [Louis Dionne's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtU51Ytfe04) on the subject; libraries to do this also include [Facebook's Folly.Poly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Poly.md). If you're new to C++ and OOP, I'd stick with traditional polymorphism, however.)

Comment: Do you need smart pointers? No, you can use raw pointers, but smart pointers are the _smarter_ way to go because they manage ownership for you. See Herb Sutters GOTW #[89](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/), [90](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/), and [91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) to learn more.

Comment: I plan to read about smart pointers in the close feature.I just want to finish this project I am currently working on right now.One last question,since I will be using `std::vector<sf::Drawable *> vec` I need to push references right?E.g. `vec.push_back(&str)`

Comment: Yes, but that's technically pushing pointers rather than references (in a loose sense, they amount to the same thing, but in strict sense `int*` is a pointer and `int&` is a reference. You are pushing the former, not the latter.)